# How to convert field to show date and time in SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have column that looks like this:

```
Jan  8 2013  2:47PM
```

but I want to convert and show something like this:

```
01/08/2013 2:47 PM
```

I have tried something like this but it does not show the time:

```
select convert (date, Date,101)as MyDate
```

Comment: what type is your original field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if your original field is a varchar: you can do something like this:

```
select CONVERT(varchar(10), CAST('Jan  8 2013  2:47PM' AS DATETIME), 101) + ' ' + RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, 'Jan  8 2013  2:47PM', 100), 7)
```

Just replace the string with your field.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:-

```
   Convert(datetime, '01/08/2013', 103)
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server does not provide a way of doing this using a single CONVERT statement, but you can use the following to achieve the objective:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, date, 101) + RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, date, 100), 8)
```

Comment: Don't forget to replace 'date' with your variable name, and I forgot to put 'AS MyDate' on the end (apologies).